# UILabel conflicts with CGRect and UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uilabel, cgrect

I have a UILabel that is dynamically modified via the following code:

```
self.labelOne.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", self.valueOne, self.valueTwo];
```

where `valueOne` and `valueTwo` are of type `NSNumber` and `NSString`, respectively.

Further down, I scale add an image to the view with the following code:

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:newImage];
CGRect frame = imgView.frame;
imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

double aspectRatio = imgView.frame.size.height / imgView.frame.size.width;
frame.size.width = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - 10;
frame.size.height = frame.size.width * aspectRatio;
imgView.frame = frame;

[imgView setCenter:CGPointMake((([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width/2)+5), (([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - (imgView.frame.size.height / 2)) - 5))];
```

Currently this works all fine and dandy, but if I try to add any other text to `labelOne`, such as the following:

```
self.labelOne.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Additional text %@ %@", self.valueOne, self.valueTwo];
```

I get a runtime error, pointing to the line `imgView.frame = frame;`.  Commenting this line out removes the runtime error, but also prevents the image from being drawn in the view.

**NOTE** It is interesting to note, though, that any modifications to the label's text *after* the variable references has no runtime error. e.g.

```
self.labelOne.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ additional text after references", self.valueOne, self.valueTwo];
```

What is happening?  The runtime error I get (when adding text *before* the variable references) is the following:

```
<Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. 
This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is 
thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. 
This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error 
in an upcoming update.
```

Please let me know if there is any more code I can supply to help with this.

***SOLUTION***

This whole mess came as a result of deleting a UILabel in the storyboard builder and not removing the references to it in the code.  The IBOutlet property still existed in the .h file, and so no errors were called in the .m file, even though the field technically no longer existed.

Problem solved, entirely a creation of my own mistake.

Comment: How do you allocate the label?

Comment: The label was created in the storyboard view and then an IBOutlet property was added in the .h file.  The label works fine when written as `self.labelOne.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", self.valueOne, self.valueTwo];` but any text before the two referenced variables causes it to blow up.  Even if I take out all of the references and just put a string of characters, I get the same issue.

Comment: And when I comment out the `imgView.frame = frame;` line, I still get error messages in the log, but the program doesn't crash.

Comment: I've implemented the code you posted, and I don't get the error message nor does it crash. I also added new text to labelOne without issue. Which OS are you using to test?

Comment: For 6.0.  I'm not too sure why it isn't working.  Even adding a simple string like `self.labelOne.text = @"Simple String";` makes it angry.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about the error message. Does it crash if you programmatically add the label?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57961/discussion-between-birrel-and-code-monkey).